# 403 Error while accessing s3a using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

**ISSUE:**

Able to successfully download the file using AWS CLI as well as boto 3.
However, while using the S3A connector of Hadoop/Spark , receiving the below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.parquet.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: BCFFD14CB2939D68, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: MfT8J6ZPlJccgHBXX+tX1fpX47V7dWCP3Dq+W9+IBUfUhsD4Nx+DcyqsbgbKsPn8NZzjc2U
```

**Configuration:**
Running this on my Local machine

1. Spark Version 2.4.4
2. Hadoop Version 2.7

Jars added:

1. hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
2. aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar

**Hadoop Config:**

```
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", session_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com") # yes, I am using central eu server.
hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```

**Code to Read the file:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(path)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: I've been facing this too; I accidentally stumbled on; https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/ while trying to fix this. So I decided to install a non hadoop bundle of spark and install a better versioned hadoop (2.4.5 and 3.2.1). But still get exactly the same issue as you, albeit a more elaborate error message (non null AWS Error Code) `Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 41...; S3 Extended Request ID: JCAO0...), S3 Extended Request ID: JCAO0...`

Answer (score 1):

Set AWS credentials provider to profile credentials:

```
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider")
```

Comment: I am facing this issue too. and not able to solve till now.can anyone suggest what I should do ?

Comment: Thanks you! This pointed me in the right direction, in my case I had to use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider` in order to connect to MinIO from pyspark 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as above. It turns out that I needed to add in the session token into my configuration. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html).

```kotlin
configuration.set("fs.s3a.session.token", System.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"))
```